# Parsing YouTube JSON

Tags: ios, json, youtube-api

I'm having trouble parsing JSON from YouTube. I'm trying to get the title, videoId, and default thumbnail URL. I've parsed JSON before but I'm having issues getting what I want from this.

Here is my code. It's crashing with an unrecognized selector error on `NSDictionary* snippet = [item objectForKey:@"snippet"];` The error is `-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108781b0`

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define storeURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=UUkfYL7q5G8CYtZgtSAwmwzw&key=AIzaSyBS4do208_KPGHAhszfVkHadSvtfSgr7Mo"]

#import "KFBYoutubeVideosTableViewController.h"
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "TSMessage.h"
#import "TSMessageView.h"

@interface KFBYoutubeVideosTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation KFBYoutubeVideosTableViewController
@synthesize title, videoID, thumbURL, url, titleArray, videoIDArray, thumbArray;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[SVProgressHUD appearance]setHudBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[SVProgressHUD appearance]setHudForegroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading"];

    Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(networkStatus == NotReachable)
    {
        [TSMessage showNotificationWithTitle:@"Network Error" subtitle:@"No active network connection!" type:TSMessageNotificationTypeError];
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    }

    self.title = @"KFB Videos";

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=UUkfYL7q5G8CYtZgtSAwmwzw&key=AIzaSyBS4do208_KPGHAhszfVkHadSvtfSgr7Mo"];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if (data == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"data is nil");
        }
        else
        {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
        }
    });
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSError *error;
    titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    videoIDArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    thumbArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", json);

    for (NSDictionary *item in json)
    {
        NSDictionary* snippet = [item objectForKey:@"snippet"];
        title = [snippet objectForKey:@"title"];
        videoID = [[snippet objectForKey:@"resourceId"] objectForKey:@"videoID"];
        thumbURL = [[[snippet objectForKey:@"thumbnails"] objectForKey:@"default"] objectForKey:@"url"];

        [titleArray addObject:title];
        [videoIDArray addObject:videoID];
        [thumbArray addObject:thumbURL];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [titleArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    }
    if (cell)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.text = [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    NSLog(@"Title: %@, Video ID: %@, Thumbnail URL: %@", [titleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[videoIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], [thumbArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    etag = "\"bvxF-DWHx1toJotsdJBeCm43SLs/tyIRY5zDT7R6YEirBFeFh0tVLCw\"";
    items =     (
                {
            etag = "\"bvxF-DWHx1toJotsdJBeCm43SLs/ON_wGC8nyy0H_bqRqQHlA7mXiM0\"";
            id = UUstIg9nSlWxTaKpWq7G0sppJf9oH5NaDE;
            kind = "youtube#playlistItem";
            snippet =             {
                channelId = UCkfYL7q5G8CYtZgtSAwmwzw;
                channelTitle = "Kentucky Farm Bureau";
                description = "Celebrate June as National Dairy Month with a visit to Jericho Acres Dairy Farm in Henry County.";
                playlistId = UUkfYL7q5G8CYtZgtSAwmwzw;
                position = 0;
                publishedAt = "2014-05-22T12:28:03.000Z";
                resourceId =                 {
                    kind = "youtube#video";
                    videoId = VSCr40jERks;
                };
                thumbnails =                 {
                    default =                     {
                        height = 90;
                        url = "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/VSCr40jERks/default.jpg";
                        width = 120;
                    };
                    high =                     {
                        height = 360;
                        url = "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/VSCr40jERks/hqdefault.jpg";
                        width = 480;
                    };
                    maxres =                     {
                        height = 720;
                        url = "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/VSCr40jERks/maxresdefault.jpg";
                        width = 1280;
                    };
                    medium =                     {
                        height = 180;
                        url = "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/VSCr40jERks/mqdefault.jpg";
                        width = 320;
                    };
                    standard =                     {
                        height = 480;
                        url = "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/VSCr40jERks/sddefault.jpg";
                        width = 640;
                    };
                };
                title = "Kentucky Farm Bureau Reports June 2014";
            };
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely title is not at bottom of the json response. Everyone of those nodes is a dictionary. So to get the things you want from your code you have to do this :

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray *items = [json objectForKey:@"items"];
for (NSDictionary *item in json)
{
    NSDictionary* snippet = [item objectForKey:@"snippet"];
    title = [snippet objectForKey:@"title"];
    videoID = [[snippet objectForKey:@"resourceId"] objectForKey:@"videoId"];
    thumbURL = [[[snippet objectForKey:@"thumbnails"] objectForKey:@"default"] objectForKey:@"url"];
}
```

If you are planning to do more stuff with this data i recommend you create objects and parse the json when creating each object. so you can keep track of other properties in future. It is much cleaner then this way.

Comment: The app crashes with an unrecognized selector error on NSDictionary* snippet = [item objectForKey:@"snippet"];

Comment: I have updated my response. The json object you get is an NSDictionary not an Array so you first have to get the items array from there and then you can iterate through it.

Comment: That fixed most of it but videoID is NULL.

Comment: I'm guessing that's because videoId is not a string.

Comment: No its because i write the key wrong i wrote VideoID it should be videoId . I fixed it in my answer

Comment: Of course. My first thought was that it was typed wrong. I looked at that but just missed it. I had it in my code ad videoID. Thanks!